# GitHub error - "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer"

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I just generated ssh keys in my Git Bash for an app I want to push to GitHub. I added the agent and agent identity, copied the key and created a new SSH Key in my GitHub account. When I try to run `$ssh -T github@github.com` I get an error message that says `"ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer"`. I have seen this questioned posed before but not directly in relation to GitHub (correct me if I am wrong). I see my id_ras and id_rsa.pub files in my User\.ssh folder. What could be the problem causing this error message? Note: I am running this inside my office and wonder if this could be caused by the office network firewall?

Comment: Checkout this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151860/ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer, that seems to be similar to your problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First `ssh -T github@github.com` would not work
`ssh -T git@github.com` would

Second, if you have any proxy/firewall in your office, outgoing ssh connection should be blocked.
Using an https URL (with credential caching) is your best option.

Comment: You are correct, that was a typo. And you are also correct in that it was in fact, the network firewall. When I got home and ran the same command, it worked perfectly. I suspected this was the case.